# Slicing plot using different colors - manually recolor the bars

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I would like to slice my `DF` using chosen colors. I know how to slice `DF`but I don't know how to put all together in a one plot. Now **MWE** gives plots like this: [image: output]

```
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np

 index=pd.date_range('2011-1-1 00:00:00', '2011-1-31 23:50:00', freq='1h')
 df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(index),2).cumsum(axis=0),columns=['A','B'],index=index)

 df2 = df.groupby([lambda x: x.month, lambda x: x.day]).sum()

 df2[:11].plot(kind='bar', color='r')
 df2[12:].plot(kind='bar', color='y')
```

I would like to have **one** plot (not two as in example) with all 31 values, where for range`[:11]` the plot color would be red and for `[12:]` yellow.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I've updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to concatenate each so that they are separate series.  You also need to rename them so they are not exactly the same (I've appended a space).

```
df3 = pd.concat([df2[:11], df2[12:]], axis=1)
df3.columns = ['A', 'B', 'A ', 'B ']
df3.plot(kind='bar', colors=['r', 'r', 'y', 'y'])
```

Alternatively, specify the color for each value in the series.

```
colors = tuple(['r'] * 11 + ['y'] * (len(df2) - 11))    
df2.plot(kind='bar', color=[colors], legend=False)
```

[image]

Comment: It is almost what I need. The desired output would have only 2 elements in the legend. The most important thing is that your code produces plot for 4 series and it gives unnecessary white space between bars.

Comment: The fundamental problem is that your are mixing your series (i.e. red/yellow).  You cannot show A with two colors in the legend.  What are you expecting?  Regarding 4 vs. 2 series, I'll see if I can revert back to two and manually recolor the bars.

Comment: You can ignore the legend.

Comment: Is it possible to to use `mask` function in this plot ? To do something like this `plot(x,y) mask=x>11 plot(x[mask],y[mask],'y')`